# SOAPUI open source includes C-DATA tag when the response includes utf-8

Tags: soapui

I am using SOAPUI open source version 5.4.0 for testing the REST API's.

My request is as below :

```
> GET
> http://IP/test/APITest?request=getaccount&loginname=test&password=test&apiversion=1.4&sessionid=cWhQWk93V0ldJkG93J3BR6FwkAZhC%2FANVb%2FthhxCUYtlpdo3W6S3v3HZIJYFHGrHZDsW8653s71XLolQCsoVp6PHWaOUdULq%2F35BlQ1gK4uc5LNt4qFGMqAnIZj%2Bgxamunwi2rF12nC%2BkyKy1ClhQzHl0VuF8vKt9OQLMfnXnS1aQTrZOYXIm5PIVuwPiD4zBlKcRvfFCVRLVbGa9qUQ0ajdOiyivDhbsZGoYKC7Fns1rfVQtKu16UbCUI2yJOd3ou070IvZ4hGisJ6oyIbgr%2F6N8KiskHkhDf%2F0y3ZXnATEpoRuoLtY6QkaopbVUoW%2FnWnEqCRyTxPefBnJQ385047Dk2vnPfkAxO7Fp2dttqcarvp4v5MgNpbHsZNqGI9M809VgD3xOUHfHgE0BKB0TtQ2362Irt26wgB7YCqwd%2BIZcTBbxfpTeZeyDwY%2FwbgY52Dg3L1uffTBU8Ny5fR6iUUZI9Xe34BWMCwuiigopGBHZWQkuzRJiA%3D%3D&device=desktop&currency=CAD
```

The response is accepted to be as below :

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>   <RSP request="test" rc="0"> 
> </RSP>
```

But when the response gets the encoding="UTF-8" SOAPUI converts the response as

```
> <data contentType="application/xml; charset=utf-8"
> contentLength="381"><!   [CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <RSP request="test" rc="0">  </RSP>]]></data>
```

I dont know why it is adding CDATA and other additional stuff.Due to this the assertions are failing`

Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Can you please add complete raw request and response. Seems issue with **Content type**.

Comment: Please post the your assertion script which is being failed.

Comment: This issues is resolved  . There was a setting in the .net framework that was turned off by the developers